# why say the פסוק of ויהי נועם before mitzvos?

Tags: tefilla, mysticism-kabbalah, taamei-mitzvot-reasons

it seems that, at least according to nusach sefard and I would assume edut hamizrach, that before mitzvos and brachos we say this pasuk. Particularly before the bracha of sefiras haomer most have this minhag, but I saw in the siddur Matok Midvash I see it before almost all brachos including Baruch she'amar. I would assume it's על פי קבלה  but I would love to see a source and a reason.

Comment: I think there is a Midrash stating that when Aharon exited the Mishkan after serving there the first time, he raised his hands and blessed everyone by saying *Veyehi Noam*. The words convey a blessing that relates to the relationship of G-d blessing us when we perform his mitzvoth, and, in turn, we should find their performance pleasant to both us and him.

Comment: "I see it before almost all brachos" Perhaps they think the blessings Chazal enacted to be said as preparation before Mitzvot are insufficient preparation?

Comment: "I see it before almost all brachos" - Well, it's not before many of them. In Nusach Ashkenaz, I've seen it before Sefirat Ha'omer and it may be before Mitzvat Lulav. It's not before Kiddush, candle lighting, putting on tallit or tefillin, and many others. Can you narrow down where you've seen this - what type of brachot? That info may help distinguish a pattern. I'm unfamiliar with siddur "Matok Midvash". Can you provide a link or is this on hebrewbooks.org?

Answer (score 3):

Likutei Maharich page 15 mentions that one should say ויהי נועם before doing Mitzvos based on the Zohar Parshas Yisro.

[Torah Lishmo - (Rabbi Yosef Chaim - Ben Ish Chai) page 30](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=15114&st=&pgnum=36&hilite=) bottom right says one should say ויהי נועם before doing Mitzvos. The reason mentioned is that if the Mitzva is done without knowing the secrets of the Mitzva it will still be accepted.

Comment: צעטל קטן של בנועם אלימלך, גם עבודת הקודש ל היחיד"א

Comment: Quite interesting. Though, I'm not sure why he seems to think this is a necessary aspect of performing the mitzvah. There is a large opinion that states that most mitzvoth do not require kavanah, yet one still obtains credit for doing them.